# Does setImageResource pick the image from correct drawable folder

Tags: android, imageview

I have a simple code like this:

```
LinearLayout mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.main);
ImageView item = new ImageView(this);
item.setImageResource(R.drawable.logo);
mainLayout.addView(item);
```

Image in the ImageView looks a bit blurred. Seems like its picking the image from **default drawable folder** instead of **drawable-hdpi**.

Because when I set the same image in the **xml**, it looks perfect.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/logo" />
```

how to make setImageResource pick the image from the right folder?

Thank You

Comment: It may because you must be viewing your layout which is supporting the `hdpi` resolution in grapical view and programmatically you may be running your application in lower resolution which may be taking image from `drawable` not `drawable-hdpi`. That may be the reason.

Comment: **programmatically you may be running your application in lower resolution** - Then It must have picked images from drawable-ldpi right? Because I have placed the image in all the folders.

Comment: Yes its like that only. It will take the image from relevant folder based on resolution of the device automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in manifest:

```
 <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Comment: Those settings are already present in the manifest. All the screen sizes and densities are supported.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but , It may because you must be viewing your layout which is supporting the `hdpi` resolution in graphical view and programmaticlly you may be running your application in lower resolution which may be taking image from `drawable` or other folder not `drawable-hdpi`. That may be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

**`setImageResource` DOES pick the image from correct drawable folder**, as long as I tried on SDK-17.

I just create three **different** pictures with the **same name** in res/drawable, res/drawable-hdpi, res/drawable-xhdpi folders respectively and run the following pieces of code:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_imageview);
    LinearLayout mainView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_view);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.dataark);

    ImageView iv2 = new ImageView(this);
    iv2.setImageResource(R.drawable.dataark);
    mainView.addView(iv2);
```

Both the ImageView added in xml(iv) and the ImageView added programmatically(iv2) loads the Image from res/drawable-xhdpi, i.e., correct folder for Samsung Galaxy Note.

So it is pretty sure that `setImageResource` DOES pick the image from correct drawable folder.

FYI, the layout xml is quite simple, as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```